# Embed document in xlsx file with POI

Tags: apache-poi

Is there any way to embed a document (e.g. pdf) in an xlsx file using Apache POI? It seems you can read embedded documents using `workbook.getAllEmbedds()`, but I can't find a way to insert any when writing a file.

Comment: Do you want to view the document inside the worksheet or embed it, so when the user double-clicks it gets opened in a new window/the corresponding application?

Comment: Until now, there's no easy way. I have found a small research for this topic. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453259/poi-importing-new-fonts-to-the-poi/22453696#22453696.

Answer (score 1):

This should help: [similar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi) User has created a patch for Apache poi with which you can include arbitary file into excel sheet [patch link here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55578)

Hope this helps.