# POI - Importing new fonts to the POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can i import a new font to POI API  with extensions ttf & otf , without install these fonts into the environment ?

> Is there a jar that i should update it with the path of the new font ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look: maybe you can use embedded object.

Comment: Do you mean you want to embed a font into an existing file, so it's somehow available when someone loads the file on a machine without the font, or do you mean to make the font available to Java so POI can correctly calculate font sizes?

Comment: Yess, I want the put the file somewhere that make once the jar of the project installed in any environment no need to install the font first

Answer (score 2):

#### Normally

You cannot add fonts... 
You can think your (office) files just like HTML. Font lives outside the document. You just set the font name, family, etc.

#### Update:

However, someone has already tried to do that. Using embedded files, you could add font files.

Link:

http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Font-embedding-into-XSLF-td5713937.html

It is far from easy. There's no easy way to insert embedded files.

- [Embed files into Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi)
- [Embedding HSSF(excel) into HSLF(ppt) using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849102/embedding-hssfexcel-into-hslfppt-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime [I've implemented an API](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63028) to embed the fonts easily.
This version goes live with POI 4.1.0.

POI can't consume .ttf/.otf directly, but needs some help from googles sfntly.
My demo project can be found under [github/poi-font-mbender](https://github.com/kiwiwings/poi-font-mbender).

I won't provide a copy & paste of the [sample class](https://github.com/kiwiwings/poi-font-mbender/blob/master/src/de/kiwiwings/poi/sl/font/SlideShowFontEmbedder.java) as you also need the rest of the sfntly library, which is not available as maven artifact.