# Embed files in java using POI-XSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to embed files 
`(.ppt(x), .doc(x), .jpg, .txt,...)`
 in excel `(format xlsx)` using Java Apache POI.
 I have found an example to embed files in excel (format xls) using 
POI-HSSF

([Embed files into Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi)),

but this example does not work with excel xlsx format. 
Does somebody know if it is possible to do this using `POI-XSSF` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: Did you take a look at similar previous discussions? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280687/embed-document-in-xlsx-file-with-poi

Comment: I've answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40476821/2066598

Answer (score -1):

'try this it works for me...' use this jars to run this code.....
1) poi-3.13-20150929.jar
2) poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar
3) poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar

```
 public String getReport() throws RecordNotFoundException{ 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cstm = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        HttpServletRequest request;
        HttpSession session;
        request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(
                "com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest");
        session = request.getSession();
        conn = JndiConnection.getOracleConnection();
        String sReportName = "";
        ArrayList<String> mainData = new ArrayList<String>();
        conn = JndiConnection.getOracleConnection();
        cstm = conn.prepareCall("your procedure name");
        cstm.setString(1, first parameter);
        cstm.setString(2, second parameter);
        cstm.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cstm.execute();
        rs1 = (ResultSet) cstm.getObject(3);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();
        String sColumnData="Sr.No";
        for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                sColumnData+="~~" + rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        }
        String headerString=sColumnData.replace("Sr.No~~", "");
        mainData.add(headerString);
        while (rs1.next()) {
            System.out.println("data...............::" + rs1.getString(1));
            String sData = "data";
            for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String column=rs1.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    if (column == null) {
                        String finalData = "";
                        sData += "~~" + finalData;
                    } else {
                        sData += "~~" + rs1.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                    }
            }
            String bodyData=sData.replace("data~~", "");
            mainData.add(bodyData);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("main data...............::" + mainData);
        session.setAttribute("myReportData", mainData);
            sReportName = genReport(mainData, title in file, "file path");
            if (!"".equals(sReportName)) {
                session.setAttribute("myReportDataExcelFile", sReportName);
            }

        setFileInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sReportName)));
        setFileName(new File(sReportName).getName());

    } catch (SQLException se) {

        throw new RecordNotFoundException(se);
    } catch (NestableException ne) {
        throw new RecordNotFoundException(ne);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RecordNotFoundException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            JndiConnection.freeConnections(cstm, conn, rs, rs1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}"
```

'Above method will get the from database and put it into the list, now use bellow method
to write xls file with POI HSSF.'

```
        private String genReport(ArrayList<String> arrDisplayDataList, String FileName, String sTitleName, String sPath)
        throws Exception {
    String fileNameWithPath;
    Exception exception;
    int col = 0;
    int sno = 1;
    fileNameWithPath = "";
    String sFromate = "";
    Connection con = null;
    String ColumnDataList[] = null;
    System.out.println("::::: Inside genReport() 2:::::");
    try {
        String[] arrColumnList = arrDisplayDataList.get(0).split("~~");
        System.out.println("Length:::" + arrColumnList.length);
        if (arrColumnList.length > 1) {
            System.out.println("==Inside Of Record Data===");
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            sFromate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            FileName = (new StringBuilder()).append(FileName).append("_").append(sFromate).toString();
            fileNameWithPath = (new StringBuilder()).append(sPath).append("/").append(FileName).append(".xls")
                    .toString();
            File f1 = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(sPath).append("/").append(FileName).append(".xls")
                    .toString());

            f1.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            HSSFSheet sheets = wb.createSheet("Sheet" + (sno++));

            int row = 1;
            HSSFRow rows;
            if (row == 1) {
                rows = sheets.createRow(0);

                HSSFCell cells = rows.createCell(0);
                cells.setCellType(1);
                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle1.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle1.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle1.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle1.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cells.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
                cells.setCellValue(sTitleName);

                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                HSSFFont fontStyle = wb.createFont();
                cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
                fontStyle.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
                fontStyle.setBoldweight((short) 700);
                fontStyle.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
                cellStyle.setFillPattern((short) 1);
                cellStyle.setFont(fontStyle);
                cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);

                cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

                cells.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                sheets.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, arrColumnList.length - 1));
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 50; columnIndex++) {
                    sheets.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
                }

            }
            rows = sheets.createRow(row++);
            for (col = 0; col < arrColumnList.length; col++) {
                HSSFCell cells = rows.createCell(col);
                String sVal = (String) arrColumnList[col];
                cells.setCellType(1);
                cells.setCellValue(sVal);
                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                HSSFFont fontStyle = wb.createFont();
                fontStyle.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
                fontStyle.setBoldweight((short) 700);
                fontStyle.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
                cellStyle.setFont(fontStyle);
                cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                cells.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 100; columnIndex++) {
                    sheets.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
                }

            }

            int rownum = 2;
            int rowcount = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < arrDisplayDataList.size(); i++) {
                if (rownum >= 65000) {
                    sheets = wb.createSheet("Sheet " + (sno++));
                    rownum = 0;
                }
                rows = sheets.createRow(rownum++);
                String sData = ((String) arrDisplayDataList.get(i)).toString();
                String sSplitData[] = sData.split("~~");

                int xcount = 0;
                for (col = 0; col < sSplitData.length; col++) {

                    HSSFCell cells = rows.createCell(xcount++);

                    String sVal = sSplitData[col];

                    if (sVal.equalsIgnoreCase("Total")) {

                        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                        HSSFFont fontStyle = wb.createFont();
                        fontStyle.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
                        fontStyle.setBoldweight((short) 600);
                        fontStyle.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);

                        cellStyle.setFont(fontStyle);

                        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                        cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                        cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                        // cells.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                        cells.setCellType(1);
                        for (int k = 3; k < rows.getLastCellNum(); k++) {// For
                                                                            // each
                                                                            // cell
                                                                            // in
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // row
                            rows.getCell(k).setCellStyle(cellStyle);// Set
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // sty;e
                        }
                        cells.setCellValue(sVal);
                        System.out.println("TTT:" + sVal);

                    } else {
                        /*
                         * HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                         * cellStyle
                         * .setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                         * cellStyle
                         * .setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                         * cellStyle
                         * .setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                         * cellStyle
                         * .setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                         * //cells.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                         * cells.setCellType(1);
                         */
                        cells.setCellValue(sVal);

                    }

                }

            }

            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } else {
            fileNameWithPath = "NO RECORD FOUND";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception ::::" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return fileNameWithPath;
}
```

Comment: I do not see the part where an external file is attached,