# Embed files into XSSF sheets in Excel, using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have found [kiwiwings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066598/kiwiwings) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757439/63436) to the question of how you can embed files into Excel using Apache POI, but unfortunately his answer only covers HSSF spreadsheets (the XLS format), and we are currently using the new XSSF format (XLSX), and the solution proposed for HSSF spreadsheets will not work. I tried porting it, but the final nail in the coffin comes from the fact that there is no HSSFObjectData equivalent in the XSSF world.

This is what I have done so far - I have found a way to attach the files to the Excel file. This code does it:

```
private PackagePart packageNotebook(
    final OPCPackage pkg,
    final String notebookTable,
    final String taskId,
    final String notebookName,
    final byte[] contents
) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException
{
    final PackagePartName partName =
        PackagingURIHelper.createPartName( "/notebook/" + notebookTable + "/" + taskId + "/" + notebookName );
    pkg.addRelationship( partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML );
    final PackagePart part = pkg.createPart( partName, "text/xml" );
    IOUtils.write( contents, part.getOutputStream() );

    return part;
}
```

I was also able to create the image I wanted to use as the anchor in the Excel file. What I am unable to do, however, is to "link" that image to the embedded content, as kiwiwings was able to do in his reply.

My end goal is to have an XLSX Excel file with embedded objects in it, in such a way that the user can double click in the anchor I open in the cells and then be able to edit the file, just like you would do if you were embedding a file using the Excel client.

Does anyone have a working example on how to do that?

Comment: Hi @ravi-wallau, you can find a work-in-progress paste @ http://pastebin.com/mgh8nevF
This is working in Excel 2016, but not in the Excel-Viewer (because I haven't implemented VML Drawings) and also not in Libre Office. But my original sample file of Excel2016 also didn't work in Libre Office

Comment: Ok the pastebin stuff works now, i.e. excel viewer doesn't complain anymore, but it's still not showing because of the omitted vml drawings ... but to my embarrassment I've realized, that I've implemented embedding of other office documents whereas you wanted to simply include arbitrary files ... :S

Comment: @kiwiwings I will check it out now!

Comment: @kiwiwings The files I will be including are simple html files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compared to the [HSSF/Package Manager stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910503/embed-files-into-excel-using-apache-poi/17757439#17757439) this was more straight forward. :)

So as usual I've started by creating the necessary file via Excel 2016 and checked what's inside the xmls. Office likes to put a lot of [AlternateContent tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478576.aspx) in - in the below solution I've removed those wrappers and directly provided the elements within the original "Choice" elements, at least with Excel2016 it works ... - be aware that the embeddings in the original files of Excel2016 couldn't be opened in Libre Office 5 / Excel-Viewer, so your users need a normal installation.

As I've implemented it in the full developer codebase of POI, you might need use the [full schemas](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

The preview pictures will be replaced when the users tries to open the embedded objects. It would be nice if POIs WMF packages could be used to generate preview images on the fly, but I only have implemented them read-only up till now :(

If the embedded elements can't be opened, please drop me a line of your users Office installation and I try to downgrade accordingly.

```
package org.apache.poi.xssf;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.ClassID;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartName;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipTypes;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagingURIHelper;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.TargetMode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Ole10Native;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Ole10NativeException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextBox;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTOfficeArtExtension;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTOfficeArtExtensionList;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTTwoCellAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTOleObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTOleObjects;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet;

public class TestEmbed {
    static final String drawNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main";
    static final String relationshipsNS = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships";

    // write some embedded objects to sheet
    @Test
    public void write() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet();

        int imgPptId = addImageToWorkbook(wb, "ppt-icon.jpg", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        int imgPckId = addImageToWorkbook(wb, "PackageIcon.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

        String imgPckRelId = addImageToSheet(sh, imgPckId, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        String imgPptRelId = addImageToSheet(sh, imgPptId, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

        // embed two different HTML pages via package manager
        XSSFClientAnchor imgAnchor1 = new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3);
        String oleRelId1 = addHtml(sh, 1);
        int shapeId1 = addImageToShape(sh, imgAnchor1, imgPckId);
        addObjectToShape(sh, imgAnchor1, shapeId1, oleRelId1, imgPckRelId, "Objekt-Manager-Shellobjekt");

        XSSFClientAnchor imgAnchor2 = new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 7, 3);
        String oleRelId2 = addHtml(sh, 2);
        int shapeId2 = addImageToShape(sh, imgAnchor2, imgPckId);
        addObjectToShape(sh, imgAnchor2, shapeId2, oleRelId2, imgPckRelId, "Objekt-Manager-Shellobjekt");

        // embed a slideshow (no package manager needed)
        XSSFClientAnchor imgAnchor3 = new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 7, 10);
        String oleRelId3 = addSlideShow(sh, 1);
        int shapeId3 = addImageToShape(sh, imgAnchor3, imgPptId);
        addObjectToShape(sh, imgAnchor3, shapeId3, oleRelId3, imgPptRelId, "Presentation");


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bla.xlsx");
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();

        wb.close();
    }

    // read Ole10Native objects from workbook
    @Test
    public void read() throws IOException, XmlException, Ole10NativeException {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("bla.xlsx"));
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        CTWorksheet cws = sheet.getCTWorksheet();
        if (!cws.isSetOleObjects()) {
            System.out.println("sheet has no ole objects");
        } else {
            Set<Integer> processedShapes = new HashSet<Integer>();
            for (XmlObject xOleObj : cws.getOleObjects().selectPath("declare namespace p='"+XSSFRelation.NS_SPREADSHEETML+"' .//p:oleObject")) {
                XmlCursor cur = xOleObj.newCursor();
                String shapeId = cur.getAttributeText(new QName("shapeId"));
                String relId = cur.getAttributeText(new QName(relationshipsNS, "id"));
                cur.dispose();

                if (processedShapes.contains(Integer.valueOf(shapeId))) {
                    continue;
                }
                processedShapes.add(Integer.valueOf(shapeId));

                PackagePart pp = sheet.getRelationById(relId).getPackagePart();
                if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject".equals(pp.getContentType())) {
                    InputStream is = pp.getInputStream();
                    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
                    is.close();
                    Ole10Native ole10 = Ole10Native.createFromEmbeddedOleObject(poifs);
                    poifs.close();
                    System.out.println("Filename: "+ole10.getFileName()+" - content length: "+ole10.getDataSize());
                }
            }

        }
        wb.close();
    }



    // add a dummy html to the embeddings folder
    private static String addHtml(XSSFSheet sh, int oleId) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        String html10 = "<html><body><marquee>This is the end. Html-id: "+oleId+"</marquee></body></html>";
        Ole10Native ole10 = new Ole10Native("html"+oleId+".html", "html"+oleId+".html", "html"+oleId+".html", html10.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(500);
        ole10.writeOut(bos);

        POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        poifs.getRoot().createDocument(Ole10Native.OLE10_NATIVE, new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));

        poifs.getRoot().setStorageClsid(ClassID.OLE10_PACKAGE);


        final PackagePartName pnOLE = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName( "/xl/embeddings/oleObject"+oleId+".bin" );
        final PackagePart partOLE = sh.getWorkbook().getPackage().createPart( pnOLE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject" );
        PackageRelationship prOLE = sh.getPackagePart().addRelationship( pnOLE, TargetMode.INTERNAL, POIXMLDocument.OLE_OBJECT_REL_TYPE );
        OutputStream os = partOLE.getOutputStream();
        poifs.writeFilesystem(os);
        os.close();
        poifs.close();

        return prOLE.getId();
    }


    // add a dummy slideshow to the embeddings folder
    private static String addSlideShow(XSSFSheet sh, int pptId) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        XSLFTextBox tb = ppt.createSlide().createTextBox();
        tb.setText("this is the end - PPT-ID: "+pptId);
        tb.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(100,100,100,100));

        final PackagePartName pnPPT = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName( "/xl/embeddings/sample"+pptId+".pptx" );
        final PackagePart partPPT = sh.getWorkbook().getPackage().createPart( pnPPT, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" );
        PackageRelationship prPPT = sh.getPackagePart().addRelationship( pnPPT, TargetMode.INTERNAL, POIXMLDocument.PACK_OBJECT_REL_TYPE );
        OutputStream os = partPPT.getOutputStream();
        ppt.write(os);
        os.close();
        ppt.close();

        return prPPT.getId();
    }



    private static int addImageToWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook wb, String fileName, int pictureType) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        int imgId = wb.addPicture(fis, pictureType);
        fis.close();
        return imgId;
    }

    private static String addImageToSheet(XSSFSheet sh, int imgId, int pictureType) throws InvalidFormatException {
        final PackagePartName pnIMG  = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName( "/xl/media/image"+(imgId+1)+(pictureType == Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG ? ".png" : ".jpeg") );
        PackageRelationship prIMG = sh.getPackagePart().addRelationship( pnIMG, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.IMAGE_PART );
        return prIMG.getId();
    }


    private static int addImageToShape(XSSFSheet sh, XSSFClientAnchor imgAnchor, int imgId) {
        XSSFDrawing pat = sh.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFPicture pic = pat.createPicture(imgAnchor, imgId);

        CTPicture cPic = pic.getCTPicture();
        int shapeId = (int)cPic.getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().getId();
        cPic.getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().setHidden(true);
        CTOfficeArtExtensionList extLst = cPic.getNvPicPr().getCNvPicPr().addNewExtLst();
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd911027(v=office.12).aspx
        CTOfficeArtExtension ext = extLst.addNewExt();
        ext.setUri("{63B3BB69-23CF-44E3-9099-C40C66FF867C}");
        XmlCursor cur = ext.newCursor();
        cur.toEndToken();
        cur.beginElement(new QName(drawNS, "compatExt", "a14"));
        cur.insertAttributeWithValue("spid", "_x0000_s"+shapeId);


        return shapeId;
    }



    private static void addObjectToShape(XSSFSheet sh, XSSFClientAnchor imgAnchor, int shapeId, String objRelId, String imgRelId, String progId) {
        CTWorksheet cwb = sh.getCTWorksheet();
        CTOleObjects oo = cwb.isSetOleObjects() ? cwb.getOleObjects() : cwb.addNewOleObjects();

        CTOleObject ole1 = oo.addNewOleObject();
        ole1.setProgId(progId);
        ole1.setShapeId(shapeId);
        ole1.setId(objRelId);


        XmlCursor cur1 = ole1.newCursor();
        cur1.toEndToken();
        cur1.beginElement("objectPr", XSSFRelation.NS_SPREADSHEETML);
        cur1.insertAttributeWithValue("id", relationshipsNS, imgRelId);
        cur1.insertAttributeWithValue("defaultSize", "0");
        cur1.beginElement("anchor", XSSFRelation.NS_SPREADSHEETML);
        cur1.insertAttributeWithValue("moveWithCells", "1");

        CTTwoCellAnchor anchor = CTTwoCellAnchor.Factory.newInstance();
        anchor.setFrom(imgAnchor.getFrom());
        anchor.setTo(imgAnchor.getTo());

        XmlCursor cur2 = anchor.newCursor();
        cur2.copyXmlContents(cur1);
        cur2.dispose();

        cur1.toParent();
        cur1.toFirstChild();
        cur1.setName(new QName(XSSFRelation.NS_SPREADSHEETML, "from"));
        cur1.toNextSibling();
        cur1.setName(new QName(XSSFRelation.NS_SPREADSHEETML, "to"));

        cur1.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've applied a patch via [#60586](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60586), so embedding is now much easier. The following snipplet is taken from the [corresponding JUnit test](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/ss/tests/usermodel/TestEmbedOLEPackage.java?view=markup).

```
Workbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sh = wb1.createSheet();
int picIdx = wb1.addPicture(getSamplePng(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
byte samplePPTX[] = getSamplePPT(true);
int oleIdx = wb1.addOlePackage(samplePPTX, "dummy.pptx", "dummy.pptx", "dummy.pptx");

Drawing<?> pat = sh.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = pat.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 6);
pat.createObjectData(anchor, oleIdx, picIdx);
```

Comment: I've created bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62017 for a problem that I've found when testing it - it fails when a certain number of OLE objects are added to a sheet.

Comment: What's the difference between the three "dummy.pptx" arguments?