# Embed or Attach zip file into XSSF sheets in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ole, embedding

I am creating a excel sheet using Apache POI where I need to embed/ atttach a zip file in a particular cell. If anyone can tell me how to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657133/2066598